# Android Preferences Error in Double

Tags: android, android-preferences

Hi I would like to ask why is that everytime I add a string and convert it into double it would only give me the 2nd digit number example I put 14 then when I load it, it will be as 4.0 can anyone help me here's my code

*Java Code

```
Double UsageValue;
String UsagePref;


UsagePref = CalculationPrefs.getString("UsagePref", "0");

Usage.setText(UsagePref);

// On Button Click
UsagePref = Double.toString(UsageValue);
editor.putString("UsagePref", UsagePref);
editor.commit();
```

Thanks in advance ^_^

~~ Edit

Just noticed when I type a number that is in the range of my values if remove the 1st digit

Comment: Show how you're grabbing the `usageValue`, please

Comment: what ever you are asking is not clear. please clarify what you want to achieve and also post the code where you are initialising `UsageValue`

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same number as Usage text. the UsageValue is just the text in Usage also whatever I type in the Usage it is equal to UsageValue

Comment: Instead of using `Double.toString(UsageValue)`, try `String.valueOf(UsageValue)` or simply `UsageValue+""`